# A better way of getting sizes of subdirectories

Tags: bash, awk, find, directory-structure

I was trying to figure out the sizes of some subdirectories in a shared folder, and was wondering if there is a 'one-liner' out there that can do this (for all of you crazy awk guys)...

The one hiccup with my situation is that I might not have permissions to some of the subfolders, so the directory size is going to be a best-effort, as we may get a 'permission denied' response to a recursive command.

Here is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/my/shared/folder/*

for d in $DIR
do
    if [ -d $d ]
    then
        dirsize=$(du -sh $d 2>/dev/null | cut -f1)
        echo "$dirsize - $d"
    fi
done
```

The `2>/dev/null` is important because of the permissions issue that may arise, so we don't want to see errors.  I also want to see the entire path, which is why

Anyone know of a more creative way of doing this?  I imagine that `find`, combined with `awk` in some capacity could generate the one liner needed to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't understand your needs. Why is `du -hs *` not good enough?

Comment: You probably meant `du -sh */`. OP's script only lists subdirectories. Files are skipped. If you need the `-` use `du -sh /my/shared/folder/*/ 2>&- | sed $'s/\t/ - /'`

Comment: I want the full file path.  `du` does not give the full path.  And as Socowi's example showed, I need to avoid 'file permission' issues which a standard `du` will output.

Comment: I just know, that find -type d and more tunning provides possibility to run command on each line via -exec param, maybe this can lead to desired results ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is the full path then you can do

```
du -hs /my/shared/folder/*/
```

If you want to supress errors from your output:

```
du -hs /my/shared/folder/*/ 2>/dev/null
```

And as pointed out by [Socowi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6770384/socowi), if you want the output to be separated by a dash instead of a tab you can manipulate it with `sed`:

```
du -hs /my/shared/folder/*/ 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\t/ - /'
```

Comment: We have a winner.  Perfect.  I guess the trailing */ on the filepath is what I wasn't thinking of.  I knew you smart people would have something for me.  I appreciate it.